# Tracking scripts and Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I'm using Google Analytics on my static website that I'm hosting on azure blob storage (static website), and using Azure CDN to secure it. (otherwise I don't really need a CDN, my page isn't particularly high traffic.)

I've noticed, though, that my filters in GA don't seem to work anymore. I assume it has to do with the IP address of the CDN provider somehow? I'm not very well versed in how CDN's work, but I thought it would work since it's a client side script, after all.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Frank, Can you provide more details including error messages as well as the GA issue you were encountering ? This would help us scope the issue and help you better.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see my description was a bit unclear. They do work - but the IP exclusion filters are ignored. For example, if I make it ignore our IP - GA still registers page-views from us.